# Unable to get VLookup property from WorkSheetFunction class

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner in using vba trying to do simple program, it has a listbox once the user click the item from the list box the other information of this item should appear in the form.

```
      Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
       Dim ename As String
       Dim star As Integer


             ename = ListBox1.Value
             Lblname.Caption = " Employee Name: " & ename

             star = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ename, Range("employee"), 4, False)

              LblStart.Caption = "Time to come:  " & star
         End Sub
```

it display an error massage

Unable to get VLookup property from WorkSheetFunction class

Comment: The error means that the Vlookup failed for some reason. Either it didn't find a match, or you specified an invalid column number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the VLookup method of the Application object instead.  As such, when there's no match, you'll get a ***non-breaking*** error, for which you can test using the IsError function.  So, for example, first declare star as a Variant, since VLookup can also return an error...

```
Dim star As Variant
```

Then test the result as follows...

```
star = Application.VLookup(ename, Range("employee"), 4, False)

If Not IsError(star) Then
    LblStart.Caption = "Time to come:  " & star
Else
    LblStart.Caption = "Time to come:  N/A"
End If
```

***Edit***

Since your lookup range is in the second column of Range("employee"), you'll need to use INDEX/MATCH.  Therefore, try the following instead...

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

    Dim ename As String
    Dim vMatchVal As Variant

    ename = ListBox1.Value
    Lblname.Caption = " Employee Name: " & ename

    With Application
        vMatchVal = .Match(ename, .Index(Range("employee"), 0, 2), 0) '2 = second column
        If Not IsError(vMatchVal) Then
            LblStart.Caption = "Time to come:  " & .Index(Range("employee"), vMatchVal, 4) '4 = fourth column
        Else
            LblStart.Caption = "Time to come:  N/A"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you this line implemented will, but now I have another error for the second line        `LblStart.Caption = "Time to come:  " & star`  the type is mismatch

Comment: Once you've tested for an error, you'll need to take the appropriate action.  See my edit.

Comment: It worked! Thanks, but I don't know why every time give me " Time to come: N/A"  even if I tried it with different column I suppose it didn't recognize the excel sheet

Comment: It means that there's no match.  If there should be a match, check for extra spaces and spelling mistakes.

Comment: Is the scope for your defined name a worksheet?  If so, you'll need to add a reference to the worksheet, for example ---> `worksheets("sheet2").range("employee")`

Comment: I added this reference but never changed!

Comment: Add a break point at the line `star = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(...)`, then try it again.  This time, when it stops at that line, move your cursor over `ename`.  What does it display?  And can that value be found in the first column of `Range("employee")`?

Comment: if I put worksheetFunction it display an error massage "Unable to get VLookup property from WorkSheetFunction class"ename display the name of employees in the list box and It worked.  I tried all columns but never find a value

Comment: Sorry, I meant `star = Application.VLookup(...)`.  But that means there's no match.  Anyway, try it again, and see what `ename` displays.  Does the value appear in the first column of `Range("employee")`?

Comment: sorry I didn't get you some how! how I see what `ename` displays? If you mean I see in the line `ename = Listbox1.value`  then it displays the name of employee

Comment: Does the name of that employee appear in the first column of `Range("employee")`?  If so and you still get `Time to come: N/A`, you likely have extra spaces somewhere or some sort of spelling mistake.

Comment: No it appear in the second column of `reange("employee")` whats the problem with it?

Comment: You're great. Cheers